# SQL For a given primary key, I want to add data that matches up

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I am creating a table in mySQL from other tables,

In my table I have identified MemberID as the primary key. How do I import data from other tables that matches up to the MemberID.

For example

My Table:

MemberID        Age

4                        12
 5                        23
 6                        45

And I would like to add Eye color matched to the MemberID from:

MemberID        Eye Color

6                        Green
 4                        Blue
 5                        Brown

I'm very new to mySQL so I apologize if this is a basic question.

Comment: Are you trying to build a query string or add a new column (Eye color) to the first table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UPDATE` with `JOIN` (after adding new column in New Table):

```
Update Table1 t1
  JOIN Eye ey
    ON t1.MemberID = ey.MemberID
SET    t1.EyeColor = ey.`Eye Color`;
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7529/1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must give names to your table.

Lets assume the first table is called table 1 and the second table is called table2.

Then you can do something like

```
SELECT t1.MemberID, t1.Age, t2.EyeColor FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.MemberID = t2.MemberID;
```